# YII Console Application (CConsoleCommand)

Tags: yii, console-application, cron

Good time! There is a project on Yii, you need to organize operations for CRONu through console applications. Once a month, the script adds a record to the table.

```
class ZpEduCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
public function run($args) {
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES     ("123123","2014-12-01 00:00:00","123")');
$command->execute();
}
```

All works well. If so put the date, nothing is added.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES ("123123","' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '","123")');
$command->execute();
```

Comment: You forgot to chain the `->execute();` i.e. `Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO text(ID, datee, ggg) VALUES ("123123","' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '","123")')->execute();`

Comment: ->execute(); there, just unfinished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `ID` is not primary key in table because primary key should be unique but in your example they are the same.

Also better use query builder for operations with database:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->insert('text', array(
    'datee'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'ggg'=>'123',
));
```

Comment: The problem is not in the primary key.
In the config console application prescribed time zone:     'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',